# enableAutoTierToHotFromCool Does not move from cool to hot

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have some Azure Storage Accounts (StorageV2) located in West Europe. All blobs uploaded are by default in the Hot tier and I have this lifecycle rule defined on them:

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "moveToCool",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "enableAutoTierToHotFromCool": true,
            "tierToCool": {
              "daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Somehow the uploaded blobs are moved to cool but then after I access them again, in the portal they still appear under Cool tier. Any idea why? (I have waited more than 24 for the rule to be in effect)

Some more questions about: "enableAutoTierToHotFromCool": true:

does it depend on the blob size? (for example if some blobs were moved to cool and then they accessed simultaneously the time between a 1 Gib is moved back to hot is the same for 10KiB blob)

does it depend on the number of blobs that are accessed? (it there a queue and if multiple blobs from cool are accessed in the same time, the requests are served based on a queue order)

Answer (score 0):

The `enableAutoTierToHotFromCool` property is a Boolean value that indicates whether a blob should automatically be tiered from cool back to hot if it is accessed again after being tiered to cool.

**And to apply new policy it takes 48hrs,  and enableAutoTierToHotFromCool": true doesn’t depend on size of blob  , and not depends on the number of blobs**

[image]

If you enable firewall rules for your storage account, lifecycle management requests may be blocked. You can unblock these requests by providing exceptions for trusted Microsoft services. For more information, refer this document [the Exceptions section in Configure firewalls and virtual networks.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#exceptions)

**A lifecycle management policy must be read or written in full. Partial updates are not supported. So try with writing**

```
"prefixMatch": [
            "containerName/log"
          ]
```

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal#code-view):